# Conditional formatting of a cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to conditional format a cell based on an outcome in another cell. In a situation where I need to deviate from a base number temporarily, I put the base number in and then minus it by the number of staff I am reducing by. e.g. 7-1. When I have this situation, I want to high light the staffing state column in a colour that shows that i have reduced the staff required for the shift. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx0Op.png)

I have conditional formatting rule "Use the formula to determine which cells to format" and used the formula =countif(n8."-") but it is not working. I am hoping that when I put the 7-1 into the cell it will highlight the staffing state column.

Comment: The fact that it shows "3-1" suggests that it is a string, not a number.  If you do `=3-1`, does it work?

Comment: No. It is not a string there is a formula =LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(N8,{"+","-"}),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",N8)),SUM(t*{1,-1}),SUM(--t))) that enables me to adjust the staffing required up or down from the base number. I dont highlight if the staff state is even and if I cap staff it will be even but want it to highlight that we have capped staffing.

Comment: It IS a string, otherwise TEXTSPLIT and COUNT wouldn't work.  So, you want some cell to be a different color if N8 contains a hyphen?

Comment: Yes that is right. if we are reducing the staffing base the column will be 3-1, 3-2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*` wildcard in your criteria.
`=countif(N8."*-*")`